# Caesar’s cipher encryption program in C

Tags: c, encryption, cs50, caesar-cipher

I am using this code for Caesar’s cipher encryption program. c = (alpha + k) % 26; //c = cipher text ASCII code, "alpha" alphabet ASCII code, "k" key for cipher text; this equation gives me zero(0) on all the 26 alphabets.

Thank You!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (int argc, string argv[]) {

    // took key from user and converted it to int
    int k = atoi (argv[1]);

    // get plaintext from user
    string p = GetString ();

    int c = 0, alpha = 0;

    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(p); i < n; i++)
    {
        // if it is alphabet else if not alphabet
        if (isalpha (p[i]) == true) {

            // if it is capital case else lower case
            if (isupper(p[i]) == true) {
                alpha = p[i] - 65;

                // add key to plaintext then take modulas
                c = (alpha + k) % 26;

                alpha = c + 65;
            } else {
                alpha = p[i] - 97;

                // add key to plaintext then take modulas
                c = (alpha + k) % 26;

                alpha = c + 97;
            }

        } else {
            alpha = p[i];
        }

        printf("%c \n",  alpha);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using C or C++.  You say C but you tagged as C++.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: And unrelated to your problem, but please try to avoid [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29), like for example `65`. Use proper character literals like `'A'` instead.

Comment: Interesting, never seen `int main (int argc, string argv[])` before.

Comment: Incomplete code. Possibly no one but your class has cs50.h. Your code will not compile without it.

Comment: @kfsone Agree. I suspect that `string` is a macro subsitition hidden inside cs50.h

Comment: @kfsone yes "string" and "GetString" are the functions of cs50.h library.

Comment: cs50.h is the class. I am compiling with it on "cloud 9 cs50 ide".

Comment: @JoachimPileborg How would I use 'A' instead of "p[i]" in the loop.

Comment: Warning on terminology. cs50.h is a header file, not a class. It may contain a class among other things. `string` cannot be a function based on the way it is being used. In cs50.h there is most likely a line something like `#define string char *`

Comment: Example of what Joachim Pileborg is suggesting: `alpha = p[i] - 65;` would be `alpha = p[i] - 'A';`

Comment: @WeatherVane I wrote all this code by myself. Sorry about this my English is grammatically not very well.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank You! Let me try this. I will let u know what happens.

Comment: @Saad my apologies too for misunderstanding.

Comment: @user4581301 The CS50 Library is a suite of C, Ruby, PHP, and Python code designed to simplify certain tasks, particularly user input (for C) and authentication (for PHP, Python, and Ruby). Source: "https://manual.cs50.net/library/".

Comment: Also on magic numbers, you can replace `97` with `'a'`.

Comment: It's less primitive than I suspected: `typedef char* string;` and it answers one of the earliest questions posed in the comments. This is C, not C++. You won't get any classes here. Be careful if you use this header with C++ code, and most definitely do not `using namespace std;` or you'll have a naming conflict between `string`s.

Answer (score 2):

From documentation of [`isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha)

> Each of these routines returns **nonzero** if c is a particular
>   representation of an alphabetic character

So when you say `if (isalpha (p[i]) == true)` you are comparing what ever **non-zero** value returned by `isalpha()`(**which may not be 1**) with **1**(`true`) which may not hold true and that `if` block will not be executed. The same goes for `isupper()`. So basically i don't think the equation is giving you zero, its just the `if` block the equation is in is not being executed.

You may want to do:

```
if (isalpha(p[i])
{

   if (isupper(p[i])
   {
      //your code
   }
   ...//your code
}
```

Comment: I never use the bool additions to C, this is one reason why. `0` is false, anything else is true. `if (isalpha (p[i]) != false)` is unnecessarily clumsy, when the language idiom is `if (isalpha (p[i]))`.

Comment: @Weather Vane Exactly!

Comment: @kfsone you should make this answer. It solved my issue.